# angular material theming defining custom colors after upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I recently upgraded to newer version of angular material 16 and now the old way of theming is no longer working. it was defined as below

```
$mat-cbh-primary: (
  50 : #e9eaf1,
  100 : #c9cadc,
  200 : #a5a6c5,
  300 : #8082ad,
  400 : #65689c,
  500 : #4a4d8a,
  600 : #434682,
  700 : #3a3d77,
  800 : #32346d,
  900 : #22255a,
  A100 : #9da1ff,
  A200 : #6a70ff,
  A400 : #373fff,
  A700 : #1e26ff,
  contrast: (
      50 : #000000,
      100 : #000000,
      200 : #000000,
      300 : #000000,
      400 : #ffffff,
      500 : #ffffff,
      600 : #ffffff,
      700 : #ffffff,
      800 : #ffffff,
      900 : #ffffff,
      A100 : #000000,
      A200 : #ffffff,
      A400 : #ffffff,
      A700 : #ffffff,
  )
);

$cbh-primary: mat-palette($mat-cbh-primary);

.sg-text-color {
    color: mat-color($cbh-primary)
}
```

now i am using the new way as:

```
$mat-cbh-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 600);
$mat-cbh-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$mat-cbh-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);


$cbh-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $mat-cbh-primary,
   accent: $mat-cbh-accent,
   warn: $mat-cbh-warn,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config($font-family: '-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Ubuntu;'),
 density: 0,
));

@include mat.core-theme($cbh-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($cbh-theme);
```

however i am not sure how to change this one to work

```
.sg-text-color {
    color: mat-color($cbh-primary)
}
```

so what is the way to use colors like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `'get-color-from-palette'` to do the following:

```
.sg-text-color {
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($mat-cbh-primary, default);
}
```